# Keeping packages.config and nuspec in sync

Tags: nuget

I've been resorting to manually modifying my .nuspec files every time I update packages. Is there an automatic way of doing this? I'd rather not have to create an additional build step that compares both files and syncs them.

I believe MyGet does this OOB, but unfortunately I can't use MyGet for this specific package.

(FWIW, I'm using VS2015 and Xamarin Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `nuget pack` against the `csproj` instead of `nuspec`, for example:

`nuget pack X.csproj`

In addition, you'll have to remove the dependencies from the `nuspec`, otherwise nuget will get it from there instead of from `packages.config`.

BTW, check the created `nupkg`. It may have unwanted files added to it, like, for instance, `txt` files, if you happen to have any in your project.

If that's the case, you'll have to invoke `nuget pack` with the `-Exclude` parameter:

`nuget pack X.csproj -Exclude **.txt`

Comment: Does this work when multitargeting? ie, I have one csproj for PCL, another for Xamarin.iOS and another one for Xamarin.Droid - all using the same resulting .package

Comment: Are your dependencies different depending on the target profile?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you then :( I think you'll have to resort to the build step or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a quick C# script (LINQPad rules) that syncs .config and .nuspec using XDocument, NuGet.Core and LINQ. If anyone's interested, I'll post it as a gist.